# Forcing r to accept "\" into a string to pass as a regular expression to an API [r]

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to pass `sessions::condition::ga:pagePath=~search\.html|/content/dam/downloaded_assets/`

as a regular expression into an API call through r. The `Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""sessions::condition::ga:pagePath=~search\."` happens when I try to pass this string.

I am aware that in r I would need to escape twice `(\\)` for r to accept the string and not throw an error. However, to the API there's a difference between

```
search\\.html
```

and

```
search\.html
```

where the second example gives me the results I want. Is there any way to force r to not throw an error and pass the string as written above? Or is there another solution?

Thank you

Comment: So what happened when you tried `search\\.html`?

Comment: r has no problem with it. The Core Reporting API gives me fewer results because it is looking for a page path with "search\.html" (or some variation with a backslash instead of properly escaping for the dot) instead of search.html

Comment: Maybe try passing it to URLencode first.  `stuff <- "sessions::condition::ga:pagePath=~search\\.html|/content/dam/downloaded_assets/"
URLencode(stuff)`

Comment: @ddunn801, doing that gives me the same results when i run it through r as the non-URL encoded results from GA's query explorer so i feel confident in using it. I'll mark it as the answer if you want to submit it below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass it to URLencode first.

```
stuff <- "sessions::condition::ga:pagePath=~search\\.html|/content/dam/downloaded_assets/"
URLencode(stuff)
```